# Strange results for hard coded bytes in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm debugging some CCCrypto code in Cocoa and I noticed the IV I'm hard setting (yes, I know it should be randomized) is giving me weird results when I debug.

This is my IV:

```
unsigned char iv[17] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x00};
```

And this is the contents of my memory after I step past the above line when debugging:

```
(lldb) p iv
(unsigned char [17]) $1 = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\x0e\x0f\x10"
```

Where do \a\b\t\n\v\f\r come from? I fully expected to see

```
\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the normal representations of those character values in ASCII and UTF-8. Remember, these may be eight-bit integers, but they're being interpreted as characters in a string. The character with the value 7 is `'\a'`, also known as the "bell character" (it is supposed to make your computer beep if you print it). The character with the value 8 is backspace, or `'\b'`. 9 is tab, or `'\t'`. Then come line feed, vertical tab, form feed and carriage return.